# Which SQL database for Tornado has an asynchronous driver?

Tags: python, tornado

I am looking for an SQL database I can use with Tornado, that supports:

- asynchronous I/O and
- Object Relational Mapping (ORM) data access.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/wiki/Links#async-client-libraries-built-on-tornadoioloop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a list of all libraries supporting asynchronous I/O in Tornado:

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/wiki/Links#async-client-libraries-built-on-tornadoioloop

Here is a talk I gave on this exact subject:

http://www.pyvideo.org/video/3698/from-synchronous-to-asynchronous-postgres-with-to

If you want both asynchronous I/O and a full fledged ORM (SQLAlchemy) then look into [aiopg](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg).